# TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
sheet = wb.active
sheet.columns[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    sheet.columns[1]
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

I'm a beginner in Python and this is the first time for me to post my question.
I'm stuck with the TypeError above saying, 'generator' object is not subscriptable. I think I exactly typed the code written on a website. 
The URL of the website is https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/

Please help me to deal with this error.

Comment: This code works for me.  As @slai suggested, check your data.

Comment: Unfortunately the book has not been updated to reflect changes in the API. For ad hoc access use Python's slicing notation eg. `ws['A']` to get a list of the cells in column A.

Answer (score 16):

That tutorial was designed for an older version of the openpyxl library, 2.3.3.  Since then the behaviour of `.columns` has changed a little bit -- I'm too lazy to look up exactly when -- and now it produces a generator instead (a lazy object which doesn't actually do any work unless it's asked to.)

If you don't care much about performance, you could call `list` on the generator that `.columns` returns and then select the appropriate column:

```
>>> sheet.columns[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
>>> list(sheet.columns)[0]
(<Cell Sheet1.A1>, <Cell Sheet1.A2>, <Cell Sheet1.A3>, <Cell Sheet1.A4>, <Cell Sheet1.A5>, <Cell Sheet1.A6>, <Cell Sheet1.A7>)
>>> list(sheet.columns)[1]
(<Cell Sheet1.B1>, <Cell Sheet1.B2>, <Cell Sheet1.B3>, <Cell Sheet1.B4>, <Cell Sheet1.B5>, <Cell Sheet1.B6>, <Cell Sheet1.B7>)
```

Or select the column by name:

```
>>> sheet["A"]
(<Cell Sheet1.A1>, <Cell Sheet1.A2>, <Cell Sheet1.A3>, <Cell Sheet1.A4>, <Cell Sheet1.A5>, <Cell Sheet1.A6>, <Cell Sheet1.A7>)
```

Or -- and this might be simplest, depending on how much time you want to give to possible other problems you might encounter -- you can just downgrade to 2.3.3.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If you don't mind, please tell me how to downgrade to 2.3.3. Honestly, I have no idea about the openpyxl 2.3.3.

Comment: How did you install openpyxl in the first place?  With pip?  Conda?

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I installed openpyxl with pip.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in package's documentation, since version 2.4.0:

> ws.rows and ws.columns now always return generators and start at the top of the worksheet

So, if you want to get column 1 you can (in addition to ways already suggested by DSM) use `next()` function on the generator:

```
next(sheet.columns)
```

But if you still want to downgrade `openpyxl` to the version used in the book, try:

```
pip install -I openpyxl==2.3.3
```

Comment: How using the next method would you get column B?